# How to use the Amazon web services credentials (Access keys) in my project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, credentials

We want to use AWS services via API calls, CLI, Etc., from our on-premise infrastructure as well as from AWS cloud infrastructure.

**As we know, we can use the AWS access key as follow:**

*This is a snippet from an example*

```
// Setup AWS SNS
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {
    Message: "SMS message test",
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: '0045xxxxxxxx',
    Subject: 'Alarm',
    MessageAttributes :{
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': 'MySender'
        },
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': 'Transactional'
    }
};

sns.publish(params, function(err_publish, data) {
    if (err_publish) {}
});
```

This code uses the access keys through the environment variables.  That approach is partially accepted because you're tied to modify those environment variables to update access keys.

**So, what are the best practices or different approaches for using the access keys in a good manner?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys)
>
> Access keys consist of an access key ID (for example, AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE) and a secret access key (for example, wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY). **You use access keys to sign programmatic requests that you make to AWS if you use the AWS SDKs, REST, or Query API operations**. The AWS SDKs use your access keys to sign requests for you, so that you don't have to handle the signing process. You can also sign requests manually. For more information, see [Signing AWS API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html).
>
> Access keys are also used with **command line interfaces (CLIs)**. When you use a CLI, the commands that you issue are signed by your access keys. You can pass access keys either with the command or store as configuration settings on your computer.
>
> ### [Temporary access keys, known as temporary security credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html)
>
> In addition to the access key ID and secret access key, temporary security credentials include a security token that you must send to AWS when you use temporary security credentials
>
> #### Advantages
>
> - They are short term.
> - After they expire, they're no longer valid.
> - You can use temporary access keys in less secure environments or distribute them to grant users temporary access to resources in your AWS account.
>
> For example, you can grant entities from other **AWS accounts access to resources in your AWS account (cross-account access)**. You can also grant users who don't have AWS security credentials access to resources in your AWS account (federation). For more information, see [Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) in the IAM User Guide.

---

## Approaches for using Access keys

- ### Access keys in Environment variables

This approach is the most common for development and testing environments because they will test their developments using a close scope, likewise for scenarios where our apps are deployed within an on-premise infrastructure.

**Usage of Access keys through Environment variables (NodeJs)**

```
// Setup AWS SNS
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {...});

sns.publish(params, function(err_publish, data) {...});
```

---

- ### Access keys through instance metadata

This is the most secure way to use the Access keys within an EC2 or container because you don't need to put any Access keys neither in your code nor in Environment variables.

**Retrieving Security Credentials from Instance Metadata**

*The following command retrieves the security credentials for an IAM role named s3access.*

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access`

*The following is an example output*

```
{
    "Code" : "Success",
    "LastUpdated" : "2012-04-26T16:39:16Z",
    "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
    "AccessKeyId" : "ASIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
    "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
    "Token" : "token",
    "Expiration" : "2017-05-17T15:09:54Z"
}
```

#### IAM Roles

The IAM Roles provide a good and secure way to grant permissions to your services.

**IAM Role console**: *This is how looks like*

[image]

The IAM Role allows you to describe a policy with the specific permissions.  That role could be attached to an EC2 instance and automatically the service within it will be granted with those permissions.  So, we can execute API calls without the need to put the Access keys:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params:{Bucket: 'bucketname', Key: 'filename'}});
var body = fs.createReadStream('file_to_upload');

s3.upload({Body:body})
.on('httpUploadProgress',function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
})
.send(function(err,data){
    console.log(err,data);
});
```

As you can see, there is any Access keys in that code because the SDK will get the Access keys from `/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access`.

---

- ### Access keys within Named Profiles

The Named profiles are used for CLI (Command line interface), so you can create profiles with different usages.  For example, you can use the AWS access keys from a specific region.

The AWS CLI supports named profiles stored in the config and credentials files. You can configure additional profiles by using aws configure with the `--profile` option or by adding entries to the config and credentials files.

**The following example shows a credentials file with two profiles:**

`~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user2]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

Each profile uses different credentials—perhaps from two different IAM users—and can also use different regions and output formats.

`~/.aws/config`

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json

[profile user2]
region=us-east-1
output=text
```

**Using Profiles with the AWS CLI**

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --profile user2`

The command above will use the credentials within profile `user2`

---

## [Best practices for using Access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html)

#### Remove (or Don't Generate) Account Access Key

An access key is required in order to sign requests that you make using the AWS Command Line Tools, the AWS SDKs, or direct API calls. Anyone who has the access key for your AWS account root user has unrestricted access to all the resources in your account, including billing information. You cannot restrict the permissions for your AWS account root user.

---

#### Use Temporary Security Credentials (IAM Roles) Instead of Long-Term Access Keys

In many scenarios, you don't need a long-term access key that never expires (as you have with an IAM user). Instead, you can create IAM roles and generate temporary security credentials. Temporary security credentials consist of an access key ID and a secret access key, but they also include a security token that indicates when the credentials expire.

---

#### Manage IAM User Access Keys Properly

If you do need to create access keys for programmatic access to AWS, create an IAM user and grant that user only the permissions he or she needs. Then generate an access key for that user. For details, see [Managing Access Keys for IAM Users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) in the IAM User Guide.

**Precautions when using access keys**

- Don't embed access keys directly into code.
- Use different access keys for different applications.
- Rotate access keys periodically.
- Remove unused access keys.
- Configure multi-factor authentication for your most sensitive operations.

## Resources

- [AWS Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-security-credentials.html)
- [AWS Account Root User Credentials vs. IAM User Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html)
- [AWS Security Audit Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-security-audit-guide.html)
- [AWS Account Identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html)
- [Using Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but what is the point of asking the question and doing right away copy-paste of AWS website in response to the question? 1st - I would put a link only, 2nd - if it's something that is easy to find (3rd link on my google search page), why ask the question at all?

Comment: As you can see the resources section contains the links I’ve used to answer my question. So, you can get information in one place. Further, some paragraphs, code snippets, and images are my own.

Comment: @LechMigdalif if this is a bad answer, please can you answer the question in a better way and not only argue the way I answered it?

Comment: I actually like what Eleazar has done. On Stack Overflow it is perfectly fine to post a question and then answer it. His information is useful and will help others in their quest to work with AWS. Stack Overflow prefers that you add the information that the link provides in your post because links get changed, deleted, etc.

Comment: But, let's be honest - when the information behind that link gets changed no one will update this article on Stack Overflow. And as I wrote - this is pure copy-paste from 3rd link on google when you ask for 'how to use AWS Access Keys'. I don't see any added content (and sorry if it's there ;-)).

Comment: @LechMigdal you’re totally wrong, you need to understand how SO works.  Copy and Paste is the most used way to answer question because you’re sharing content in this site.  The most important thing is making reference sharing the links were used to answer. Further, like I said some texts are my own but that doesn’t really matter, the important of this answer is sharing content to help other people.

Comment: This helped me because I was constantly looking at the wrong place in the documentation. Googling led med here, and thus I resolved my problem.